# Laravel Livewire - how to insert model data into datetime-local input by wire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i got a HTML `<input>` of datetime-local with is wired to some model, when i want to save data its fine but when i want to load modal with data of existing model my input date-timelocal is not loading values.

```xml
<x-jet-input id="date" class="block mt-1" type="datetime-local" name="date" wire:model='date'/>
```

I tried:

```
protected $casts = [
    'date' => 'datetime:Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
];
```

But it doesnt change anythin, my `<input>` is not not loading data.
I think its becouse 'date' returns wrong format anyway. Like "2021-10-07 00:00:00".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$casts` only affects the value when it's casted to an array or json format. You'll have to format the value in the livewire component with `Carbon`'s `format`method.

`$date = $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use laravel accessor in laravel 8 you can just simply do this in your model

```
public function getDateAttribute($value)
{
    return \Carbon\Carbon::create($value)->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");
}
```

Further you can read more about accessors and mutators from the official document [Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)